# How pass to id and slug in url CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a function view, and i pass 2 parameters, $id and $slug, 
I want example.com/slug-id, then in my routes.php i have

```
   Router::connect(
'/view/:id-:slug', 
['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'view'],
[
    'pass' => ['id', 'slug'],
    'id' => '[0-9]+'
]
```

);
And my function is

```
public function view($slug = null, $id = null){
    // Time Format
    Time::setToStringFormat('dd-MM-YYYY');

    if(!$id)
        throw new NotFoundException('error !');

    $post = $this->Posts->get($id);

    if($slug != $post->slug)
        throw new NotFoundException("error");
    $this->set(compact('post'));

}
```

But why when i go to example.fr/posts/view/test-1

I have a NotFoundException ?

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action**

Comment: You see my actually function ? Is same of doc ! My question is why i have Notfoundexception ?

Comment: _I_ see your code, yes, but _you_ don't seem to, it's obvious that it's _not_ the same as in the linked docs. Maybe you should try reading what I've linked, it cleary explains how it needs to be done.

Comment: So now everything is mixed up, your route doesn't connect to `/posts/...` anymore, but the example URL points to it, the elements are in reversed order, the URLs in your answer are different and do not match the route, and the question still says that its unexpectedly throwing an exception, while your answer suggests that its not. Please, sum everything up properly, add all necessary information and your actual code, then, take a few minutes, re-read your question, and ask yourself if someone who doesn't know what you are doing will be able to understand the problem that you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Your router converts the following pattern
    /view/:id-:slug
Replace
    example.fr/posts/view/test-1 by
    example.fr/posts/view/1-test